# int value goes back to zero after closing voter app

Tags: integer, increment

so everything works but a major problem is after closing the app every value goes back to zero.
how do i prevent that from happening. i want the updated values even after app is closed and when reopen.

```
public class second_app extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView A10;
TextView A11;
TextView A12;
TextView A13;
TextView A14;
TextView A15;
TextView A16;
TextView A17;
TextView A18;
TextView A19;

Button btnA10;
Button btnA11;
Button btnA12;
Button btnA13;
Button btnA14;
Button btnA15;
Button btnA16;
Button btnA17;
Button btnA18;
Button btnA19;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_second_app );

    A10 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA10 );
    A11 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA11 );
    A12 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA12 );
    A13 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA13 );
    A14 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA14 );
    A15 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA15);
    A16 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA16 );
    A17 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA17 );
    A18 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA18 );
    A19 = findViewById ( R.id.tvA19 );
    btnA10 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA10 );
    btnA11 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA11 );
    btnA12 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA12 );
    btnA13 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA13 );
    btnA14 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA14 );
    btnA15 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA15 );
    btnA16 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA16 );
    btnA17 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA17 );
    btnA18 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA18 );
    btnA19 = findViewById ( R.id.btnA19 );
    
}

public void A10clicked (View v){
    String A10count =A10.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A10count );
    count++;
    A10.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}
public void A11clicked (View v){
    String A11count =A11.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A11count );
    count++;
    A11.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}
public void A12clicked (View v){
    String A12count =A12.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A12count );
    count++;
    A12.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}
public void A13clicked (View v){
    String A13count =A13.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A13count );
    count++;
    A13.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A14clicked (View v){
    String A14count =A14.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A14count );
    count++;
    A14.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A15clicked (View v){
    String A15count =A15.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A15count );
    count++;
    A15.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A16clicked (View v){
    String A16count =A16.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A16count );
    count++;
    A16.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A17clicked (View v){
    String A17count =A17.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A17count );
    count++;
    A17.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}

public void A18clicked (View v){
    String A18count =A18.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A18count );
    count++;
    A18.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}
public void A19clicked (View v){
    String A19count =A19.getText ().toString ().trim ();
    int count =Integer.parseInt ( A19count );
    count++;
    A19.setText ( String.valueOf ( count ) );
}
```

}

any help would be appreciated.

i tried save instance but that didnt work either i tried to implement onbackpressed but activity wont open and i am stuck on this part everything is finished.

Comment: You might want to store the data to disk somehow. You can save the value to a file and read it at program startup.

Comment: is there any way we can do it through code. for example when i rotate my app all value becomes zero but after using save instance they stay in rotate and portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

Values in variables are only stored in memory while the application is running. As already pointed out by jakub in the comment you need to use some kind of persistent storage to store your values.

There are a couple of good ways to do that, you can find a good overview in this post https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html by Lars Vogel.